# why I am not getting the inverse of this matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I want to get the inverse of the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1+\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1+\lambda & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1+\lambda & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1+\lambda
\end{pmatrix}$$

my first step was doing some cofactor expansion:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1+\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1\\
-\lambda & \lambda & 0 & 0\\
-\lambda & 0 & \lambda & 0 \\
-\lambda  & 0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}$$

then the cofactor matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^3 & \lambda^3 & \lambda^3 & \lambda^3\\
-\lambda^2 &\lambda^3+4\lambda^2 & 0 & 0\\
-\lambda^2 & 0 & \lambda^3+4\lambda^2  & 0 \\
-\lambda^2 & 0 & 0 & \lambda^3+4\lambda^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

transposing and putting the determinant:
$$\frac{1}{\lambda^3(4+\lambda)}\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^3 & -\lambda^2 & -\lambda^2 & -\lambda^2\\
\lambda^3 &\lambda^3+4\lambda^2 & 0 & 0\\
\lambda^3 & 0 & \lambda^3+4\lambda^2  & 0 \\
\lambda^3 & 0 & 0 & \lambda^3+4\lambda^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

however, according to Wolfram This is wrong I was checking the answer but I could not find my mistake

Comment: What is the value of $\lambda$? If your computation is right then the matrix has no inverse for $\lambda=0,-4$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak The invertibility was explored in questions [find the values of $\lambda$ such that this matrix is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4828810/89922) (deleted) and then [Is there a faster way to get the determinant of a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4828870/89922).

Comment: lambda= 2 I get different results with wolfram

Comment: Maybe you have obtained the inverse of the matrix after row operations, not the inverse of the original matrix?

Comment: @peterwhy thats what I did

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the matrix in question, then $A = \lambda I + vv^*$, where $v = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{1}$ so that $vv^*$ is the $4\times 4$ matrix of all ones. The [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) then yields
$$
A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda} I - \left(\frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda}\right)vv^*.
$$

In components, this is
$$
A^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\lambda} - \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \\
\frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda} - \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \\
\frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda} -  \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \\
\frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} &\frac{1}{\lambda} -  \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + 4\lambda} & \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $J$ is the matrix with all ones, the linear space of matrices of the form $aI+bJ$ is a commutative algebra. In particular the inverse of $aI+bJ$ has the form $cI+dJ$ with $c=1/a$ and $d=-b/(a^2+nab).$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the matrix in question:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1+\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1+\lambda & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1+\lambda & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1+\lambda
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the cofactors of the entries are either

$$\left\{
\pm\det\begin{pmatrix}
1+\lambda & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1+\lambda & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1+\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}, 
\pm\det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1+\lambda & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1+\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$$

Please check how you got your cofactor matrix with entries with many different absolute values.

I previously suspected that you have obtained the inverse of the matrix after row operations, not the inverse of the original matrix. But such claim is wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be the $4\times 4$ matrix with every entry equal to $1$. You want the inverse of $C+\lambda I$, where $I$ is the $4\times 4$ identity matrix. Notice that
$$
         C^2=4C
$$
Therefore $C^3=C^2C=4C^2=16C$.
Continuing in this fashion gives $C^n=4^{n-1}C$, which leads to an explicit expression for the resolvent of $C$:
\begin{align}
         (\lambda I+C)^{-1}&=\frac{1}{\lambda}(I+\frac{1}{\lambda}C)^{-1} \\
    &=\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-\frac{1}{\lambda}C+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}C^2-\frac{1}{\lambda^3}C^3+\cdots) \\
    &=\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-\frac{1}{\lambda}C+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}4C-\frac{1}{\lambda^3}4^2C+\cdots) \\
    &=\frac{1}{\lambda}I-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}(1-\frac{4}{\lambda}+\frac{4^2}{\lambda^2}+\cdots)C \\
    &=\frac{1}{\lambda}I-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{\lambda}}C \\
    &=\frac{1}{\lambda}I-\frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda+4)}C
\end{align}
You can directly check the validity of this assertion by using the relations derived above:
\begin{align}
    &(\lambda I+C)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}I-\frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda+4)}C\right) \\
   &= I+\frac{1}{\lambda}C-\frac{1}{\lambda+4}C-\frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda+4)}C^2 \\
   &= I+\frac{4}{\lambda(\lambda+4)}C-\frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda+4)}C^2 \\
   &= I+\frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda+4)}(4C-C^2) \\
   &= I.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
      (\lambda I+C)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}I-\frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda+4)}C
$$